# How to solve warning:"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'" in VScode interactive window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am running this code in interactive window,And it says that there is No module named 'pandas', yet I have install pandas already, and the code runs without problem in output,what is the problem?
[image]

Comment: This is usually that you have two Pythons installed.  You're installing modules into one of them and running from the other.  Easy to do if you're installing modules at the command line and running from an IDE.

Comment: You need to locate the python binary you used to run your code. In the terminal/shell, use `which python` if on Linux or `where python` if on Windows. Then copy the path to python (should be something like `.../python3.8/bin/python`). Then, press `Ctrl-Shift-P` in VSCode and search "python: select interpreter". Click the "Enter interpreter path" option and paste the path you copied. You'll have to restart the interactive window (and maybe VSCode entirely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed in your screenshot that the Python interpreter you are using is "`Python3.9`" (upper right corner), but there is no module "`pandas`" in this environment, so the result shows that the module cannot be found.

It is recommended that you switch the python in the upper right corner of "Interactive" to the environment used by VSCode (lower left corner of VSCode), and the module "pandas" exists in this environment.

[image]

Check the installation of the module:

[image]

More reference: [Environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal of VScode pls. run the following `pip list` . Does the package show there ? If yes, try importing it from the python terminal to verify.

If no, then you installed it in different python and you need to select the proper virtual env where you have installed by going in the python interpreter settings.

If you are on linux, easy way would be do `which python` to confirm that python is same where you have installed and where you are importing.

Comment: I used "where python" and found there are two python installed. I uninstall one of them that is not in anaconda environment and select the one left as python interpreter in VScode and restart it. If I press run bottom, the code runs in output. However, when I try again in interactive windows, the following warning pop up:

Comment: Command failed: D:/Anaconda/anaconda/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\程思瑶\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/程思瑶/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py
ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ����·����
ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ����·����
ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ����·����
ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ����·����